# JQuery Carousel - images disappearing in Chrome

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, carousel

I have a problem with a jquery carousel, occurring only in Chrome (IE and Firefox are ok).  This has just been flagged up on our live site and I'm hoping to fix it over the weekend, hence the Friday afternoon question.

On page load the first image appears as expected, then when the next  slides in (whether by timed interval or clicking the 'next' arrow) the image is not visible.  The js behaviour appears to be normal, with the .active class being moved from div to div as you'd expect.

Here's the really weird thing - if you open dev tools (F12) in the code inspector (Elements tab) and select a NON active div (a div that does not have the 'active' class) the image (in the active div) appears.

All images are available, there are no 404s and no errors in the Console.  It appears to be a strange Chrome quirk, stranger still that the behaviour is affected simply by clicking on a node in the inspector.

The site is at http://www.ftse.com/products/home.

Many thanks
Simon

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome 40.0.2214.91 (OSX).

Comment: I just checked as well and it works fine in chrome for me too. Are you sure its not a caching issue?

Comment: It seems to be another 'non-problem' then, thanks guys.